# What does it mean for a Turing machine $M$ to accept $\epsilon$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Suppose $B_{TM}$ = $\{ \langle M \rangle$ | $M$ is a Turing machine over $\{0, 1\}$ and $M$ accepts $\epsilon\}$.

I do not understand what it means for $M$ to accept $\epsilon$. Can someone explain what this language $B_{TM}$ consists of and what is $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\epsilon$ is the empty string. A Turing machine accepts $\epsilon$ if the  start state of its finite control is an accepting state.

$\langle M\rangle$ is a "description" of a Turing machine $M$.  One way to think of it is to think of any reasonable method for writing down Turing machines and then to imagine $M$ as a string written down in this way.  Another way to think of it is that every possible Turing machine  has been enumerated and listed in a big book somewhere, and then $\langle M\rangle$ is the number for the appearance of $M$ in the book, with $\langle 1\rangle$ being the first one on the first page, and so on.

$B_{TM}$ here is the set of strings $S$ such that  $S$ describes a Turing machine $M$—that is, such that $S=\langle M\rangle$—and $M$ halts on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, just didnt know what $\epsilon$ was. I just have one concern, would the length of $\epsilon$ be 0 then?

Comment: Yes, $\epsilon$ is the unique string of length 0.